# Querying public fusion table without authentication

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am trying to run a JavaScript query against a public google fusion table but cannot get it to work without some form of authentication. The complete table is accessible from the web UI with the link:

```
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1XxWDOr1-w74LEgTBW8QdWl_OYPkPcLKp0Wm5ghej
```

but a query against the table to just return the data like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201XxWDOr1-w74LEgTBW8QdWl_OYPkPcLKp0Wm5ghej
```

does not work unless I add my key on the end. Without a key I get the following error:

```
{
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
}
```

As the table is public it should be able to be queried by anyone. Does anyone know if this should actually work for version 2 of the fusion tables API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read-Queries require at least a key(which is used to authenticate your access to the API, not to the particular table)

Note: a table must be public **and downloadable**, otherwise you must authenticate via OAuth

Comment: That's what I thought but it doesn't make any sense. The original fusion table API did not have this limitation. It reduces the usefulness of fusion tables if you cannot use them from a client application.

Comment: Why can't you use it from a client-application when a key is required?

Comment: To generate the REST request using JavaScript the key would be to be visible which would allow anyone to use my key and use up my quota. It seems like this is only meant to be used from a server app where the key is not revealed.

Comment: the use of keys may be limited to domains *"extendedHelp": https://code.google.com/apis/console*

Comment: That makes some sense but it is still odd that the restriction is on the use of the API and not on the access to the data itself, you can use your key to access my table and it counts against your quota not mine. Also what do you mean it wouldn't be applicable in production, I don't see how faking the referer could be prevented (do I need another question for this?).

Comment: You would be able to fake a referer for your own PC, but not for the PC's of other users of the application(at least I don't know how to do it). I don't see any use-case for a faked referer for a single user.